# all ExifInterface value returns 0 or null

Tags: android, exif

Im trying to get the gps location of the images, but all i got is null/0, i tried to fetch other exif info from different images but the results are still either null/0

```
public void MarkGeoTagImage(String imagePath)
{
    try {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, imagePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The first toast shows the absolute path of the image like /storage/sdcard0/etp_images/test.jpg, but the second toast only shows 0 or null as results.

Comment: Try your code with your own image having  GPS longitude.

Comment: i did, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably it is not a solution, but I had some problem with `ExifInterface` before. Original class `ExifInterface` has different bugs. Try to use support version of this class. In my case it resolved my problem.
Compile this using Gradle: `com.android.support:exifinterface:25.1.0`

Comment: thank you so much! Your method actually works! Finally

Comment: I am working in xamarin android. I have install "Exif support library" but still facing using this link : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Exif/25.4.0.2 but sill I am facing issue.

Comment: Rutul, make sure you use the version from Android.Support.Media namespace, not the Android.Media version.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem so I also added the ExifInterface Support Library to my project with the following dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:exifinterface:25.1.0'
```

and also wrote the following methods in order to get the image orientation angle:

```
private int getImageAngle(Uri uri, String imagePath) {
    int orientation;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        orientation = getOrientation(uri);
    } else {
        orientation = getOrientationLegacy(imagePath);
    }

    switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            return 90;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            return 180;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            return 270;
    }

    return 0;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
private int getOrientation(Uri uri) {
    InputStream in = null;
    ExifInterface exif = null;

    try {
        in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        exif = new ExifInterface(in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }
        }
    }

    return getExifAttributeInt(exif);
}

private int getOrientationLegacy(String imagePath) {
    ExifInterface exif = null;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return getExifAttributeInt(exif);
}

private int getExifAttributeInt(ExifInterface exif) {
    if (exif != null) {
        return exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
    } else {
        return ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL;
    }
}
```