# Created Date, Latitude and longitude getting null from exifInterface in xamarin android for API 23 and above

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, exif

I am working in xamarin android native project. I want to get Attribute of selected image like created date time, latitude and longitude.

I am using "ExifInterface" for the same.

My code is

```
private void GetMediaMetadata(MediaInfoModel mediaInfo)
        {
            //TODO - ExifInterface is not working in API 23
            var exif = new ExifInterface(mediaInfo.AbsoluteFilePath);

            var createdDateFromFile = exif.GetAttribute(ExifInterface.TagDatetime);
            if (createdDateFromFile != null)
                mediaInfo.MediaCreatedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(createdDateFromFile);

            var latitude  = exif.GetAttribute(ExifInterface.TagGpsLatitude);
            var longitude = exif.GetAttribute(ExifInterface.TagGpsDestLongitude);

            if (latitude != null && longitude != null)
            {
                mediaInfo.GeoPosition = new Position
                {
                    Latitude  = Convert.ToDouble(latitude),
                    Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(longitude),
                };
            }
        }
```

Problem is :

**In API 23 and above "createdDateFromFile", "latitude" and "Longitude" are null.**

I have added following support library

> Install-Package Xamarin.Android.Support.Exif -Version 25.4.0.2

I have referred following link

> [all ExifInterface value returns 0 or null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42368235/all-exifinterface-value-returns-0-or-null)

Comment: in API 23 or above , without enable location, when you capture image , those ExifInterface are put null or 0, so you cant get it.it not necessary that every image have those params.

Comment: "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" and "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" is enable in Application manifest. Which location you are talking about?

Comment: Hardware Location?

Comment: how you get Images? from gallery or camera?

Comment: Adding using gallery

Comment: thats the issue ,image not have GPS ExifInterface , so you cant get.

Comment: What about date? Which attribute should I use instead of "TagGpsLatitude" and "TagGpsDestLongitude". Date is most important for me.

Comment: Any update??????

Comment: sorry for that, i dont know more.

Comment: I have also use exifinterface support library according to following link but still not getting answer 
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/introducing-the-exifinterface-support-library.html